# Class ID for Logging

Tags: c++, logging, embedded

I am carrying a project with some friends over a very limited (regarding to RAM memory) microcontroller. My current task is to make a logger module. The logger must show a format like "x;y;log-message" where "x" is the log level and "y" is the class identifier (unique integer number). So far I got the design pretty much finished although I'm still having problems on the way I can get the unique class ID from the logger module without any dependency (somehow).

My first idea is (let's suppose this is pseudo code):

```
class A : public Logger
{
private:
   unsigned short GetId () {return CLASS_ID_A;}
};

class Logger
{
public:
   enum
   {
      CLASS_ID_A, CLASS_ID_B
   };

   void Error (const char *msg, ...)
   {
      Log(LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, GetId(), msg, ...);
   }

protected:
   unsigned short GetId () = 0;
};
```

I do not like that all classes which have to log must inherit from Logger class. I also saw the idea from log4cpp (multiple implementations of Category class), but I think this is too complex and heavy for our needs and resources.

I will appreciate any other ideas! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create an static Log method in the Logger class and use that.

```
Logger::Log(LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, ...);
```